# Find the conditional and marginal densities?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm getting lost in notation here.

We have $f_X(x)=xe^{-x}$ and we have a new random variable, $Y$, which is uniform from $(0,X)$.

We want three things:

1. Marginal density for $Y$
2. Conditional density for $X$ given $Y$
3. Joint density function.

From the given information, the conditional density of $Y$ is $f_{Y|X=x}(y)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Since $f_{XY}=f_{X|Y}f_Y$, then $f_{XY}=f_{Y|X}f_X=\frac{1}{x}xe^{-x}=e^{-x}$.

So, then isn't the marginal density of $Y$ the value $e^{-x}$ integrated with respect to $y$? i.e., $f_Y(y)=ye^{-x}-1$.

Then, for the conditional density $X|Y$, we have:

$f_{X|Y}=\frac{f_{XY}}{f_X}=\frac{ye^{-x}-1}{xe^{-x}}$.

Is this even close to right?

Comment: Note that $f_{XY}(z)= \int_t f_{Y|X}(t) f_X(\frac{z}{t}) \mathrm dt$.

Comment: Why would you recommend introducing a new variable $z$?

Comment: It's just the variable of the function $f_{XY}$, and it's not "new".

Comment: The conditional density is **not** $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)={1\over x}$, it is $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)={1\over x}{\bf 1}_{(0,x)}(y)$. You have to take the range into account.

Comment: I don't like the indicator function. I don't know how to integrate it.